# CakePHP: how to use Controller::referer() in a view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm getting the following error:

```
Strict (2048): Non-static method Controller::referer() should not be called statically,
assuming $this from incompatible context [APP/View/Questions/admin_edit.ctp, line 20]
```

Caused by this:

```
//in app/View/Questions/admin_edit.ctp
echo $this->Html->link('Cancel', Controller::referer() );
```

Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't. You use the request object instead:

```
$this->request->referer();
```

The controller does nothing else internally.

Careful: the referer can be empty and thus you might want to provide a fallback here in that case.

Also note the optional param $local:

`@param boolean $local If true, restrict referring URLs to local server`

Comment: Thanks. For some reason when I enter the URL directly (no referer) it returns my document root (example.com) instead of my fallback. Any idea why?

Comment: This happens to me too. On my local copy, $this->referer() works fine, but on the server, it's just spitting out the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$referer_url = $this->referer('/', true); // you will get like (without base URL) "/users/profile"
$refererController = Router::parse($referer_url); // this will return $referer_url as array which contains 

Array ( 
   [controller] => users 
   [action] => profile 
}
```

if anyone face any error when you use `Router::parse($referer_url)` please add cakephp routing in your controller

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
```